# How to solve this set trigonometric equations simultaneously?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have derived the following set of equations. I would like to simultaneously solve for x, alpha and beta.

In my opinion I have 3 unknowns and three equations so this should be possible. But I cant seem to crack it. Is it possible and if so, how is it done?

$$x =-\frac{6.11149 + 105.557 \csc[\beta] \sin[\alpha]}{
  2 (15.768 + 
     1.22247 \csc[\beta] (15.768 \sin[\alpha] + 
        12.739 \sin[\alpha + \beta]))}$$
$$x = -\frac{1344.69 + 77.8543 \csc[\alpha] \sin[\beta]}{
  491.11 + 25.478 \csc[\alpha] (15.768 \sin[\beta] + 
      15.573 \sin[\alpha + \beta])}$$
$$x = -\frac{(15.573 \sin[\alpha] + 12.739 \sin[\beta]) (86.3477 - \frac{
     1022.13 \sin[\beta]}{
     15.573 \sin[\alpha] + 12.739 \sin[\beta]})}{
  2 (245.555 \sin[\alpha] + 
     12.739 (15.768 \sin[\beta] + 15.573 \sin[\alpha + \beta]))}$$

Comment: Just because there are three unknowns in three equations doesn't mean it is solvable. Some trigonometric functions like sin(x) or tan(x) can give the same solution for multiple, if not an infinite number, of values. For instance, the equation sin(x)=0 is 1 unknown in 1 equation, but it has solutions x=0, x=pi, x=-pi, x=2pi, etc.

Comment: Also, is there any specific reason to these constants? Such as being sqrt(2), or tan(3), or something, or are they just random numbers?

Comment: You can use standard numerical methods provided you have ranges for the three unknowns. In general though there are many solutions, and standard iterative methods will fail, as $\csc$ diverges periodically. Oh and btw this aint goin' analytically but you can try lol

Comment: @DanielGeyfman Thank you for your answers. I was able to get the solution by restricting alpha and beta. Thanks again!